# Modulo Operator for even, odd, odd, even, even, etc

Tags: php, operator-keyword, modulo

I'm familiar with the `Modulo Operator` in PHP, however, I'm trying to get a slight variation.

**I want it to do either:**

A) odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, etc.

or

B) even, odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd, even, even, etc.

Currently using `$i % 2` but that gets `odd, even, odd, even, etc.`. I've tried fiddling with the operator itself by changing it to a different number, but I obviously don't get the result I want.

Does anyone know how this can be realised?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `str_repeat` to do as the name suggests: repeat a pattern for string creation:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++)
{
    echo ($i == 1 ? $i % 2 : str_repeat($i % 2, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more,

```
$str= "odd,";
for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++){
    $t = str_repeat($i % 2, 2);
    $str.= (intval($t) ? str_replace("1","even,",$t):'odd,');
}
echo rtrim($str,',');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2vQiu)

**Output:-**

```
odd,even,even,odd,even,even,odd,even,even,odd,even,even,odd,even,even,odd
```

Answer (score 0):

For the series of:

```
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
```

You can also swap every 4th element with it's next element starting from 2nd location(0-based indexing) to produce series like below:

```
1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 12, 11, 13, 14, 16, 15, 17, 18, 20, 19, 21
```

**Code:**

```
<?php

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];

$i = 2;
$size = count($arr);

while($i < $size-1){
    swap($arr,$i);    
    $i += 4;
}

function swap(&$arr,$i){
    $temp = $arr[$i];
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$i + 1];
    $arr[$i + 1] = $temp;
}

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val % 2 === 0 ? "even , " : "odd , ";
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/htgMJ